# not getting push notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

Please help me since I am stuck !!! I created an app. in my eclipse that gives me the regid for the client side. I created in asp - server side and I am sending a notification to my android. I am getting this message from the server side:
id=0:1369942608307759%5252b7a166d6cf16 but nothing in my phone.... Why ? what do I have to do in order to get notification in my mobile ? It seems that every thingis going fine but for some reason I am not getting the notification...does any one knows what can go wrong ?

Comment: The response you got means that your server code is working fine (Google accepted your message for delivery). Either you have a problem in your Android app (either in the code or in the manifest) or you have a connection problem (if your device is not connected to the internet, or is connected via WiFi to a network that has a firewall). If you include your app code for receiving the notification, perhaps I'll be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer....my app code is taken from this website:http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-gcm-simple-tutorial/. Do I have to run any application to get this notification ? I tried on 3g and WiFi but got nothing...any suggestions ?